# apache: configuring routes on similar urls to different tomcat webapps

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, tomcat7

lets say I have tomcat7 running on port 8080, it has 2 webapps `webappA` and `webAppB`.

both expose an API via `/api/[entity]` in their own context: eg

`http://www.domain.com:8080/webappA/api/dog`

and

`http://www.domain.com:8080/webappB/api/cat`

what I would like to achieve, with apache httpd, is to set rewrite, or mod proxy, to make this transparent, on port 80, WITHOUT having the webapp context's in the users url.

eg

`http://www.mydomain.com/api/dog -> transparently calls http://www.domain.com:8080/webappA/api/dog`

and

`http://www.mydomain.com/api/cat -> transparently calls http://www.domain.com:8080/webappB/api/cat`

I assume what I want to do is possible, but I couldnt find anything.

I dont even mind if in my config, I have to say explicitly delare `/api/cat` goes to `webappB/api/cat` and `/api/dog` goes to `webappA/api/dog`, and if I want to add `webappA/api/mouse` in future, I would have to edit my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible using `mod_proxy` with a reverse proxy, e.g. (not tested):

```
ProxyPass /api/dog http://localhost:8080/webappA/api/dog
ProxyPassReverse /api/dog http://localhost:8080/webappA/api/dog

ProxyPass /api/cat http://localhost:8080/webappB/api/cat
ProxyPassReverse /api/cat http://localhost:8080/webappB/api/cat
```

Make sure that the `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules of Apache are enabled.

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly. I could even leave out the "/cat" from the last ProxyPass/Reverse, so it acts as wildcard if the first "test" doesnt pass